# When using UPDATE and SET with SQL rows appear to be missing

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When I run the query below :

```
SELECT COUNT(x.objectID)  
FROM db0..table0 as t  
INNER JOIN db1..table1 as x ON t.objID = x.slaveID  
INNER JOIN db1..table2 as table2 ON table2.sourceID = x.objectID  
WHERE (****)
```

I get 268'466 results. However when I update and add a column to `db0..table0` with `x.objectID` as follows, I get 145'346 of these items into my `db0.table0`

```
ALTER TABLE db0..table0 ADD new_objID bigint;

UPDATE db0..table0  
SET db0..table0.new_objID = x.objectID  
FROM db0..table0 as t  
INNER JOIN db1..table1 as x ON t.objID = x.slaveID  
INNER JOIN db1..table2 as table2 ON table2.sourceID = x.objectID  
WHERE (****)
```

Can anyone see what is going wrong? The only difference between the queries is the first line in the first query is replaced with the first two lines in the second query.

To count the number of new values that end up in my table I use,

```
SELECT COUNT(new_objID) 
FROM db0..table0
```

This should return all the none `NULL` instances of `new_objID`.

**EDIT**

So the table structures are

**table0**
table0_ID

**table1**
table1_ID
other_table1_ID
value

**table0** and **table1** are linked by table0_ID and table1_ID in a many to one relationship. One table0_ID corresponds to many table1_ID. I realised that **table2** was no longer necessary - in the past I wanted information from this table but not any longer.

Effectively all I am trying to do is add the other_table1_ID entry, which corresponds to the smallest entry of value for each group of table1_ID into **table0**.

The issue is the discrepancy between these queries suggest I am doing something wrong I just can't work out what.

**QUERY ONE**

```
SELECT COUNT(table1.table1_ID)  
FROM db0..table0 as table0 
INNER JOIN db1..table1 as table1
ON table0.table0_ID = table1.table1_ID   
WHERE table1.value IN (SELECT MIN(value)  
    FROM db1..table1 as new_table1  
    WHERE new_table1.table1_ID = table1.table1_ID)
```

**QUERY TWO**

```
ALTER TABLE db0..table0 ADD newID bigint

UPDATE db0..table0  
SET db0..table0.newID = table1.other_table1_ID  
FROM db0..table0 as table0 
INNER JOIN db1..table1 as table1
ON table0.table0_ID = table1.table1_ID   
WHERE table1.value IN (SELECT MIN(value)  
    FROM db1..table1 as new_table1  
    WHERE new_table1.table1_ID = table1.table1_ID)
```

Comment: Do you get different row counts even after you have applied the fix from my answer below?

Comment: Please edit your question and read how to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** after some discussion and question update by OP we came to the conclusion that conditions in both queries should be changed to the following:

`new_table1.table1_ID = table1.table1_ID` should instead be `table0.table0_ID = new_table1.table1_ID`

then both SELECT queries (original and the one which counts the newID field) return same count of 206146 records.

---

In the first query you do `COUNT(x.objectID)` but in the UPDATE call you `SET db0..table0.new_objID = x.objID` .

Notice, different column names: `x.objectID` in the first case and `x.objID` in the second.

Change your second query to the following:

```
UPDATE db0..table0  
SET db0..table0.new_objID = x.objectID  
FROM db0..table0 as t  
INNER JOIN db1..table1 as x  
ON t.objID = x.slaveID  
INNER JOIN db1..table2 as table2  
ON table2.sourceID = x.objectID  
WHERE (****)
```

Comment: That's what you noticed , So where is your solution? where is the answer?

Comment: @Sami, isn't the solution obvious? Anyways, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry this was actually a typo, I changed the names from the actual query (to try and make it look simpler). So this is not the issue.

Comment: @anonMouse, strange...are you sure WHERE conditions are same for both queries? Are there any triggers defined for db0..table0?

Comment: The WHERE conditions are definitely the same, I copied them across. I do not know about triggers but I will have a look. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Hey downvoters! Your comments are welcome. The answer is not relevant after the OP has edited the question but originally it had a good chance to be a solution.

Comment: there are no triggers defined for db0..table0

Comment: @anonMouse probably to help you further we need to see the complete SQL code of the first and second queries just as you have it in SSMS + we need the table structure for table0, table1 and table2. Maybe you have some computed columns in there which depend on each other and somehow affect the result. Could you post all that info?

Comment: thanks for your help, I added this information. I'm not using SSMS I'm using mxODBC.

Comment: @anonMouse yes I saw, thanks. Ok..again look you do: SET db0..table0.newID = table1.other_table1_ID but table1.other_table1_ID may not be set for ALL rows in table1, i.e. table1 may have rows where only table1_ID is set and table1.other_table1_ID is NULL. But in the first query you count table1_ID and not other_table1_ID. So you need to check if there are records in table1 which doesnt have other_table1_ID set. Run this query: select count(table1_ID) from table1 where other_table1_ID IS NULL. and let us know the result. Thanks.

Comment: I ran this and there is 0 NULL other_table1_IDs

Comment: But if you change SELECT COUNT(table1.table1_ID) from the first query to SELECT COUNT(table1.other_table1_ID) do you get 268'466 or 145'346 rows?

Comment: When I query COUNT(DISTINCT other_table1_ID) I get 268466. When I query COUNT(DISTINCT table0_ID) I get 145346. I think this must be where the issue is coming from.

Comment: so it means there are 145K records in table0 but 268K in table1. When you update table0, you update those 145K records only. But when you query SELECT COUNT(table1.table1_ID) of course you get those 268K because this query runs against table1 while the original SELECT COUNT(new_objID) FROM db0..table0 runs against 145K records in table0. There is no issue here. Just misunderstanding. Could you confirm?

Comment: sorry when I said _'COUNT(DISTINCT other_table1_ID) I get 268466. When I query COUNT(DISTINCT table0_ID) I get 145346'_  I meant within **QUERY ONE**. There's 580226 records in table0 and 73013257 records in table1. I still don't understand where this difference in records is coming from, it looks to me like multiple other_table1_ID must be linking to one table0_ID which would be incorrect if they did.

Comment: I believe the issue is that **new_table1.table1_ID = table1.table1_ID** should instead be **table0.table0_ID = new_table1.table1_ID**

Comment: @anonMouse do you get same counts if you change columns per your last post?

Comment: When I make this change I get 206146 counts from both **query 1** and **query 2**. So it seems like that has solved it! Still getting my head around it but I think I understand it. Thanks for your help I don't think I would of got there so quickly without discussing it with you!

Comment: @anonMouse I'm glad you get it solved. Thanks for the feedback. I have updated the answer text with the proper condition text.